# Gremlin on CosmosDB - Drop and recreate the properties of a vertex without deleting the vertex

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am trying to set properties on a vertex in a *partitioned* CosmosDB graph.
If the vertex had any properties previously, I want them scrubbed and replaced with the new set of properties.

Even the deleting was a bit tricky, as the 'partition key' is exposed as a non-deleteable property.

```
g.V('nodeId').has('partitionKey','xx').properties().drop()
```

-> "Gremlin Query Execution Error: The partition property cannot be removed."

Fortunately, the `id` of the partition key property is predictable and can be used for filtering it out:

```
g.V('nodeId').has('partitionKey','xx')
.properties().not(has('id', 'nodeId|partitionKey'))
.drop()
```

Now I'm stuck trying to add the new properties. I tried:

```
g.V('nodeId').has('partitionKey','xx')
.properties().not(has('id', 'nodeId|partitionKey'))
.drop()
.property('a','valA')
.property('b','valB')
```

but that looks like I'm applying the `property()` step to a (empty) list of properties, not to a vertex.
The error isn't very helpful:

```
Gremlin Query Compilation Error: Column reference R_200324["_value"] cannot be located in the raw records in the current execution pipeline.
```

I tried using applying the `property()` step to the vertex (by `select`-ing it), but I must be doing something wrong:

```
g.V('nodeId').has('partitionKey','xx')
.as('v') 
.properties().not(has('id', 'nodeId|partitionKey'))
.drop()
.select('v')
.property('a','valA')
.property('b','valB')
```

This gives the same error as above.

I also tried `.back('v')` instead of `.select('v')` but it looks like `back` is not supported in CosmosDB.

Any suggestions?

Comment: there is no `back()` step in TinkerPop 3.x - that is old syntax from 2.x

Answer (score 2):

I think you are running into the same problem as described in [this S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54091140/5490505).

Basically, the `.drop()` filters everything out of the traversal and prevents any of the following code from doing anything.

You can work around this by using `.sideEffect()` like so

```
g.V('nodeId').has('partitionKey','xx')
.sideEffect(properties().not(has('id', 'nodeId|partitionKey')).drop())
.property('a','valA')
.property('b','valB')
```