# Gremlin query to override the Vertex

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

How to write gremlin query which will do

1. Get existing vertex
2. Remove all existing properties(obviously except id, label, index property etc)
3. Add new properties with values(mostly string only)

---

Or is there any alternate way to override the vertex using gremlin query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the TinkerPop modern graph as an example:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').valueMap(true)
==>[id:1,label:person,name:[marko],age:[29]]
```

and assuming full Gremlin support you could keep the "name" property (i.e. index property) remove all other properties and add new properties in a single line of Gremlin as follows:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').
......1>   sideEffect(properties().not(hasKey('name')).drop()).
......2>   property('age',33).
......3>   property('favoriteColor','red')
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').valueMap(true)
==>[id:1,label:person,name:[marko],favoriteColor:[red],age:[33]]
```

But in CosmosDB, I don't think you yet have support for the `sideEffect()` step. The trick is that to do this in one traversal is that you need to "side-effect" the `drop()` in some way and since `drop()` behaves as a filter everything step, any steps you add after it will simply not execute as there is nothing left in the stream to operate on.

Some workaround ideas for the lack of `sideEffect()` include using `union()` with `identity()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').
......1>   union(properties().not(hasKey('name')).drop(),
......2>         __.identity()).
......3>   property('age',33).
......4>   property('favoriteColor','red')
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').valueMap(true)
==>[id:1,label:person,name:[marko],favoriteColor:[red],age:[33]]
```

Less readable than the intent of `sideEffect()` but effective. I believe CosmosDB supports `identity()` even though it is not documented on their web site. If you don't have `identity()` you just have to get creative I suppose - here's another way which is even less nice:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').as('a').
......1>   union(properties().not(hasKey('name')).drop(),
......2>         select('a')).
......3>   property('age',33).
......4>   property('favoriteColor','red')
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').valueMap(true)
==>[id:1,label:person,name:[marko],favoriteColor:[red],age:[33]]
```

Comment: Thanks @stephen-mallette, you saved my day.
`sideEffect()` step is supported in CosmosDB.
But workaround ideas were working until I add `drop()` step. After adding `drop()` it started throwing gremlin query compilation error.

Comment: hmm - they must have some restrictions there around where `drop()` can be used. at least `sideEffect()` is available. gtk - thanks